# Would nations invest in the cannon if ranged weaponry were not cost effective?

Tags: warfare, weapons

This world employs advanced magitech as a staple of life. Ironically however, warfare hasn't advanced beyond the medieval period. Weapons are imbued with runes, which infuse the object with Mana. This makes the particular weapons stronger and more capable than our weapons in the real world. Similarly, armor and shields have also adopted the practice, providing protection from imbued weapons. Warfare has revolved around these opposing forces competing against each other,with one surpassing the other at various points.

The form of warfare left out is ranged weaponry. Since every object must be imbued with runes to be effective, projectiles have not developed to the point where it can be cost effective. Every arrow or bullet that is launched would have to be imbued with Mana, which is why these kinds of weapons have fallen to the wayside.

Cannonballs are giant balls shot out of cannons. They were instrumental in the leveling of castles in Europe during the medieval/Renaissance period. However, with runes being able to shield large buildings from damage, and the inherent cost of imbuing projectiles with Mana, there is doubt to this technology ever being invented?

What would make cannons come into play under these conditions?

Comment: Do the non-magic characteristics of the magically imbued object affect its effectiveness?  For instance, does the quality of the edge of a sword or the thickness of plate armor determine to any extent the success of an attack, or is it just the power of the enchantments on the items in opposition?  Likewise, does the power of the sword mans arm impact the chance of success?

Comment: How much work does it actually take to infuse an object with mana? For instance, if you're issuing magical armor to every Tom, Dick, and Harry in your levies, that implies that it's actually quite cheap. If it's more the province of the elite, then cannons could still be useful in breaking up enemy formations.

Comment: Can runes really protect people from cannonfire? Because I imagine a cannon sending some 24 pound or 32 pound ball through charging infantry would cause slaughter unless your runes are at insane level.

Comment: @FailusMaximus magic doesn't conserve momentum, apparently.

Comment: @Cadence moreover, it implies that equipping the aforementioned TD&H with a complete suit of armour is _also_ cheap, somewhat surprisingly. I wonder if each plate needs to be imbued separately. Sounds expensive. Maybe TD&H get to wear enchanted steel dustbins like pre-industrial daleks, whilst the nobility get to wear sensible but expensive outfits?

Answer (score 1):

Retrievable ammunition would be a start.

We often think of weapons as being neatly divided into melee and ranged categories.  This is convenient for many situations, but doesn't always cover all the bases.  The Chinese have invented several weapons which somewhat straddle the line, such as the [rope dart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8j2an5krotw), [meteor hammer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOu0e6GY4ys), and [variants](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IPl2tFNihc) (along with [some](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LkyoDiHbiI) of unclear practical value)

All of these have a common trait -- the weapon stays in the possession of the owner.  It's never fully unleashed, but it has some aspects of ranged weapons that are not typically seen in melee weapons.

If a cannon's ammunition was recoverable, it would make the Mana cost of creating it less of an issue.

Also, consider seeing whether the rules on ammunition could be bent.  For example, it might be possible to make 10 rounds for a gun as one object, imbue that object, then break them apart.  That's something that's 100% dependent on your particular magic system: is it possible to break the objects without ruining the imbuing?  Perhaps its not feasible to do it for very small objects due to the challenges of controlling the process that tightly, but larger weapons such as cannons might be easier from a quality control perspective, making it easier to break them apart without ruining the imbuing.  (And they're also worth more per unit, so its worth more time to get it right)

As for protecting the buildings with the shields, that's entirely up to your particular magic system and how you want it to play out.  As a general rule, one should expect militaries *not* to use any weapon that is useless.  The wasted energy is far too precious.  Or at least, they would have to believe it was worthwhile.  If an enemy was successful in convincing them that runic protection of buildings was infeasible, an army might develop cannons to attack with.

The other answer, of course, is bureaucracy.  Your nation's cannons would not be the first time a lobbyist convinced a government to buy weapons they did not need, or the first nation who had a decade-long contract for a weapon in place before the fundamental nature of war shifted, rendering the weapon impotent.